# App doesn't print to console SearchBar.text

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making simple app with Search bar.

My goal is to put text, I'm typing in Search Bar to TableCell. But, while testing, text doesn't printing even in console.

Why can it happen so?

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("The search text is: '\(searchBar.text!)")
    searchResults = [String]()

    for i in 0...2 {
        searchResults.append(String(format: "Fake results %d for '%@'",i, searchBar.text!))
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
}

extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()

    let cellIdentifier = "SearchResultsCell"

    var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

My console is empty

Comment: Have you set the search bar's delegate property to be the instance of the SearchViewController? `searchBar.delegate = self`?

Comment: Oh, I found, where I was mistaken. I forgot to connect TableView dataSource to ViewController